# Nautilus error after update

Tags: nautilus

Running 20.04 LTS , after the latest update Nautilus fails to launch. I see the following error in the system log file;

nautilus[16257]: segfault at 2 ip 00007fd255489d5a sp 00007ffc38796ed8 error 4 in libc-2.31.so[7fd2553fa000+178000]

Any help in fixing this is appreciated.

Output of ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions;
ls: cannot access '/home/andrew/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions': No such file or directory

Output of ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions;
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Feb  9  2019 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Jan 26  2020 ..
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Feb  9  2019 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Feb  9  2019 ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com

Created new user, logged in, new user also unable to launch Nautilus.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h`. Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

Comment: memtest86 passed. Here are results of free command;                                                                   
                     total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available 
Mem:           15Gi       820Mi        13Gi       102Mi       1.2Gi        14Gi
Swap:           2.0Gi          0B          2.0Gi

Comment: Thanks for the update. Edit your question (not into the comments please) and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`.

Comment: Log into another user account (create one if you need to) and see if Nautilus launches there.